# Unity Remote 5 not connecting to Unity

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, unity-remote

I am trying to make a mobile game for Android... I am following this tutorial on YouTube: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nM0h5pQYQxM

I got to 30:58 in the video were we are getting Unity to run and project the cube on Unity Remote 5. I am using a Razer Phone running Android 7.1.1 with Unity Remote 5 installed. I have enabled Developer Settings and Editor Settings in Unity. But I am not using the cable that came from the box seeing it is Type C to Type C. I am using an Elgato Type C to USB 3.0 if that had anything to do with it.

Sorry for Dual Image: (I know it is running, I am trying to see if it will magically appear on my phone...)
[image]

Comment: kill adb from Task Manager. Start it and then start the server again. Make sure that `adb devices` can detect your phone.  See both links in the duplicate for more info

Comment: @Programmer would this be on my PC or in Unity or on my Phone. (Sorry I am very new to game dev...)

Comment: @Programmer It doesn't work

Comment: Edit your question and add what you have tried from the duplicate

Comment: @Programmer All I had to do was restart my device as well as doing what you said and it worked! Thanks soo much!